# How to let another user access my kubernetes on IBM Bluemix?

Tags: kubernetes, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-kubernetes, iks

I created a kubernetes cluster under my user account on IBM Bluemix, and added another into my organization. But he can't see my cluster. Is there any other configure?

Answer (score 2):

To manage cluster access, see [this link](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/containers/cs_cluster.html#cs_cluster_user) from the IBM Bluemix Container Service documentation.  Summarised here:

> **Managing cluster access**
>
> You can grant access to your cluster to other users, so that they can
>   access the cluster, manage the cluster, and deploy apps to the
>   cluster.
>
> Every user that works with IBM Bluemix Container Service must be
>   assigned a service-specific user role in Identity and Access
>   Management that determines what actions this user can perform.
>   Identity and Access Management differentiates between the following
>   access permissions.
>
> - **IBM Bluemix Container Service access policies**
>
> Access policies determine the cluster management actions that you can
>   perform on a cluster, such as creating or removing clusters, and
>   adding or removing extra worker nodes.
>
> - **Cloud Foundry roles**
>
> Every user must be assigned a Cloud Foundry user role. This role
>   determines the actions that the user can perform on the Bluemix
>   account, such as inviting other users, or viewing the quota usage. To
>   review the permissions of each role, see [Cloud Foundry roles](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/iam/users_roles.html#cfroles).
>
> - **RBAC roles**
>
> Every user who is assigned an IBM Bluemix Container Service access
>   policy is automatically assigned an RBAC role. RBAC roles determine
>   the actions that you can perform on Kubernetes resources inside the
>   cluster. RBAC roles are set up for the default namespace only. The
>   cluster administrator can add RBAC roles for other namespaces in the
>   cluster. See Using [RBAC Authorization](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authorization/rbac/#api-overview) in the
>   Kubernetes documentation for more information.

Comment: i find the problem i had is when i invite the new user, didn't select the right service...